# Issue connecting to Click to Deploy Cassandra instance

Tags: go, cassandra, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to write data into Click To Deploy cassandra cluster using Golang `gocql` driver from a remote machine , But it fails to connect .

Here is my cassandra.yaml configuration ,

```
native_transport: true
listen_address: <public ip>
broadcast_address: <public ip>
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
native_transport_port : 9042
```

And here is the Golang Code using which I'm remotely trying to connect

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gocql/gocql"
)

func main() {
// connect to the cluster
    cluster := gocql.NewCluster(<public ip of cassandra nodes>)

    cluster.Keyspace = "demo"
    session, _ := cluster.CreateSession()
    defer session.Close()
    if err := session.Query("INSERT INTO users (lastname, firstname) VALUES ('Karthic', 'Rao')").Exec(); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("ERror writing : ", err.Error())
    }
}
```

Here is the error , 
`connect: failed to connect to "<public ip>:9042": dial tcp <public ip> :9042: i/o timeout`

Any idea on how to fix this to make i/o on the cassandra nodes ?

Comment: Your VM's operating system may have a firewall blocking access to port 9042, and GCE may also have a firewall rule blocking access. You need to open up access in both of these firewalls.

Comment: @MishaBrukman , I have opened up the access the creating a new firewall rule , `tcp:1-65535` is the permission I've given

Comment: I'm not sure what else to do here to fix your issue, but please note that this is not a secure installation: you're giving access to your Cassandra database to the entire world, without access control. Ideally, it should only be accessible on the local private GCE network and the client should be running on GCE as well, and support some authentication / authorization mechanism itself.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to open CQL native transport port `(tcp:9042)` on your GCE firewall to be able to connect to your cluster nodes remotely. You can use `telnet <public ip> 9042` command to test if the port is open and listening. Also make sure the outgoing traffics to the port `9042` is not blocked on your remote network/firewall.

If the firewall is configured properly and you could telnet to the port but still receiving the mentioned error, then something is wrong with your gocql setup.